# Trigger filter before URLMappings in Grails

Tags: grails, filter, servlet-filters

I want to trigger a filter before going through the urlmapping, how can I do it? 
Here is a scenario, the user types in www.myapp.com/someurl and the 'someurl' is not mapped in UrlMappings.groovy, so the user will be redirected to 404 page. But I want to intercept the process before going to 404 page. The 'someurl' might be anything, it might be '/users', 'users/admin/43' or anything.

One option I found was to use servlet level filter but that seems to be causing me more trouble than I was expecting; adding this filter is not letting the page to render, I just get a blank white screen. Is there another way to doing so?

Basically, I am trying to rewrite the url before it is validated in urlmappings.

Comment: What's wrong with using a Grails filter and redirecting to the new URL that is listed in your URL Mapping? It's hard to understand from your question what you are trying to do and what problems you are having.

Comment: I've added more description to the question.

Comment: So basically you are trying to intercept something before it gets to the URLMapping and determine it's a 404?

Comment: @EddardStark mapping a url to another url using filters is not good idea, use the url mapping that is why we have them.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Yes! Exactly!

Comment: @EddardStark That's not really going to be possible considering in order to arrive at a 404 URLMappings need to be considered first. The only option I can think of is to very specifically define all your valid URLs in URLMappings and then a final catch all that will essentially be your "It didn't match anything else so it must be a 404".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to let users type in any URI they want, and then you want to check the URI yourself and possibly redirect to one of regular url mappings? I did something similar in my project, first I changed default url mapping:

```
"/url/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

then added another one

```
"/$level1/$level2?/$level3?/$level4?"(controller: 'anything', action: 'resolve') {
}
```

and then a controller similar to:

```
class AnythingController {
    def resolve(String level1, String level2, String level3, String level4) {
        if (level1 == 'music') {
            return redirect (controller: 'music')
        } else {
            // any logic you need
        }
    }
}
```

this way you can handle "anything" in the controller, and if you want to use regular /controller/action uri, then you just prepend it with "/url"

Comment: yeah, kinda like that but not exactly. We are implementing a massive url change to the whole application. So, urls like /user would be /user-area or /admin would be /admin-area and so on. The url change is very simple to do but I am worried about all the references within the application and beyond the application to these pages. So I was thinking of adding a filter or anything to redirect /user to /user-area and so on.